# Scripts cannot run simultaneously on startup

Tags: linux, shell-script, startup

I want two scripts (`Server_drive`, `Server_video_boot`) running on startup, but there is conflict between them. Specifically, there is always running the script with the lower priority. I tried with many different priority numbers, but same result.

```
root@beagleboard:/etc/rc2.d# ls
S02dbus-1    S20ffserver  S20syslog        S50usb-gadget         S70lighttpd
S10dropbear  S20gpiolow   S20wlan8192cu    S59Server_drive       S99rmnologin
S20apmd      S20samba     S21avahi-daemon  S60Server_video_boot
```

*Server_video_boot:*

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/root/
./Server_video.sh
```

*Server_drive:*

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/root/
./test     // C executable
```

Any ideas why this happens? How can I fix this?

*Info:*
*Angstrom distribution running on embedded device BeagleBoard-xM*

Comment: It's not `rc.0` that runs at start-up -- that's shutdown. `K` scripts run `stop` for that service, `S` runs `start`.  Note that lower numerical values for the priority run first.  **You have not explained what you mean by "conflict".**

Comment: We have no way of helping you without knowing what the scripts are doing and what they look like. For all we know, you have a syntax error in one of them and that's why it's not running. Please also tell us which distribution you are using since this kind of thing varies between systems.

Comment: @goldilocks I fixed `rc0.d`. By "conflict" I didn't mean anything complex, just the fact that they both can run on startup, but not simultaneously.

Comment: If I get it right, the problem is that they don't execute parallel? Then you have to enable concurrent boot as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BootProcessSpeedup#Using_insserv).

Comment: First of all, that exactly the kind of thing you should mention in your question body. Ideally, show us the content of the scripts so we can see if there is anything obvious.

Comment: @terdon `Server_video_boot` calls `Server_video.sh` and `Server_drive` calls `test` to run. `Server_video.sh` use port 8080 while `test` use port 17015. Could this cause any problem for the two executables, running in parallel?

Comment: Is this still an open problem for you? The [different ports](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140396/scripts-cannot-run-simultaneously-on-startup#comment226917_140396) aren't an issue. Is the problem that S59Server_drive stays running while S60Server_video_boot starts, and you want S59 to exit before S60 starts?